# Different terminals in Debian for root and other users

Tags: terminal, debian

I use Debian 6 and the terminal. When I type `su -l` I get something like this:

```
root@mycomputer:
```

as prompt. When I type `su -l someuser` I get this prompt:

```
$
```

There, I cannot use TAB to autocomplete paths, the source command is not known etc. How can I get the "style" of the root for every user? Does this depend on the distinction between bash, shell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it depends on which shell is used. By default, new user accounts have their shell set to `/bin/sh`, the Bourne shell, which does not support more advanced features such as line editing, completion, etc.

Use **`chsh`** to change the user's shell. For example,

```
chsh -s $(which bash) someuser
```

will change *someuser*'s shell to *bash*. You must give the full path to `-s`, and that path should be listed in `/etc/shells`.

I don't know which one you are currently using for `root`, so run **`echo $SHELL`** to find out. (Alternatively, run `getent passwd root`; the shell will be the last (7th) field.)

Answer (score 0):

Edit the user's .bashrc and enable bash completion or type `. /etc/bash_completion`.

Comment: does this enable the source command, too? I use the .profile files for all users...

Comment: `source` is a shell builtin. It doesn't need to be enabled.

Comment: `source` is a bash-specific alias for the "`.`" command. It might not exist on other shells, while `.` always works.